# "Saving up" an explanation on Orlah 3 (Tosafos Yom Tov)

Tags: commentaries, bartenura, maseches-orla

The [third chapter of Orlah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Orlah.3) lists several cases in which some illegal [*orlah*](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Orlah) produce needs to be destroyed to prevent it from being consumed or profited from. In the penultimate *mishna*, the last case with such a ruling is presented and the [Ra"av explains](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Orlah.3.6?lang=bi&p2=Bartenura_on_Mishnah_Orlah.3.6.3) why such an extreme measure as burning was needed rather than essentially giving away the prohibited material, for which their is precedent in a *mishna* in *Avoda Zara*.

The *Tosafos Yom Tov*, calling attention to Ra"av's proffering of this explanation at the last opportunity rather than the first one [says](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Orlah.3.6?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_Yom_Tov_on_Mishnah_Orlah.3.6.1)

> אכוליה פרקין מהדר לשנויי ונטר ליה עד הכא

which I take to mean

> he is turning back to teach this about our whole chapter but saved it until now.

(The rest of the comment has to do with resolving the main matter at hand - i.e. the difference between the cases in our chapter and the one in *Avoda Zara*.)

What is *Tosafos Yom Tov* adding with this comment? Is he trying to clue us in as to *why* Ra"av "saved" this explanation? It is obvious from the Ra"av's own words he didn't mean to limit his analysis to only the case in the 6th *mishna*, as he says "משום דהכא חיישינן **בכולהו**", so that can't be it.